# Is the underlying Snowflake driver pooling the connections here?

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public Connection fetchSnowflakeConnection(SnowflakeSettings settings) {
    Properties properties = getProperties(settings);
    try {
        String connectStr = null;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(settings.url)) {
            connectStr = "jdbc:snowflake://us-east-1.blah.com";
        } else {
            connectStr = "jdbc:snowflake://" + settings.url;
        }

        Driver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(connectStr);
        LOG.info("Snowflake driver version: {}.{}", driver.getMajorVersion(),
                driver.getMinorVersion());
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, properties);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Problem getting Snowflake connection with these settings: " + settings.toString(),
                e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is the connection pooled?  I am using the base java DriverManager but in Mark's world it is getting the Snowflake driver which is pooling the connection.  So

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, properties);
```

is getting a pooled connection.  Right?

Comment: I don't know Snowflake, but in most JDBC drivers, this wouldn't pool connections. In general, if you want connection pooling, you explicitly use a data source that provides connection pooling (eg c3p0, HikariCP, DBCP or others).

Comment: I agree here . Its not being connection pooled.I have used HikariCP earlier though with Snowflake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the connection pooled?

No, what you get with a [`DriverManager.getConnection(…)`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#L631-L664) API call is a newly built, independent connection object.

A [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) is a cache management function, which [this API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) and the [Snowflake JDBC driver implementation called underneath](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeDriver.java#L153-L170) does not carry or perform.

The inbuilt Java classes under the `java.sql` package offer no connection pooling features, and you'll need to use a [third-party library on top of the drivers, or roll your own cache management](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling).

[M](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver.java#L49)[o](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java#L182-L197)[st](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/afc0a13cd3c5a0bf57eaa809ee0ee6df1fd5ac9b/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L245-L247) [driver](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/Driver.java#L156-L263) [implementations](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/JDBC.java#L86-L117) are kept simple to allow users to operate with a connection pooling pattern of choice at a higher level, and do not shove-in any implicit connection pooling.

**P.s.** Although [DataSource implementations can carry some form of connection pooling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), Snowflake's implementation (`SnowflakeBasicDataSource`, as of June 2020) is an aptly-named basic one which generates a [new connection per call](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeBasicDataSource.java#L101-L127) and does not participate in pooling.

Comment: So does the SnowflakeBasicDataSource pool the connection?

Comment: I didn't think so.  There is a post here that confused me:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000098T2J9/how-to-connect-to-snowflake-db-using-connection-pooldbcp2-in-java  Just wanted a confimation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this below for Hikari CP related settings.I configured it once.

---

..

```
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "<Path to p8 file>";
private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
private static HikariDataSource ds;

private DataSource() {}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

### ..

```
    static {
    config.setJdbcUrl( "<Snowflake JDBC URL" );
   config.setUsername( "<username>" );
    config.setPassword( "<password>" );
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "cachePrepStmts" , "true" );
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSize" , "250" );
    config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" , "2048" );


   try {
  config.addDataSourceProperty("java.security.PrivateKey", PrivateKeyReader.get(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));
} catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
    ds = new HikariDataSource( config );
}
```